# Can we change the color of the overflown text?

Tags: css

If I have a `div` with `overflow: visible;`, can I make the color of the overflow text different than the color of the text inside the `div`?

Something like this (the black box is the div):

```
<div style="overflow: visible; max-width: 200px;">
    Text will for sure overflow
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you may need to use javascript or any other library

Comment: Maybe, the `filter` property can help

Comment: Maybe with a pseudo element placed over the actual div dimensions, and using `mix-blend-mode` to get it to turn red color applied to the whole text, into black again? https://jsfiddle.net/g3kw6b0c/ (Not sure whether that might collide with any additional requirements for whole page backgrounds or something though, you’d have to test it in whatever specific scenario you need it in.)

Comment: @CBroe I got a ver close result to what I want by using your code and altering it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/se7oLw34/ . I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe with a pseudo element placed over the actual div dimensions, and using `mix-blend-mode` to get it to turn red color applied to the whole text, dark again:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #f00;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  background: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div>Text will for sure overflow</div>
```

Not sure whether that might collide with any additional requirements for whole page backgrounds or something though, you’d have to test it in whatever specific scenario you need it in.

Instead of `mix-blend-mode`, applying some sort of `filter` might give similar results.

Comment: Changing the `left` in the `::after` to `cacl(100% + 1px)` will do the trick even better.

Comment: now you can safely use `inset:0` instead of top/left/right/bottom all set to 0. The support is pretty good

Answer (score 3):

`backdrop-filter` can also do it

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #f00;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Text will for sure overflow</div>
```

Or use background coloration like below:

```css
.box {
  --d:100px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: var(--d);
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box span {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,#000 calc(var(--d) + 3px),red 0); /* we need to account for the padding */
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>Text will for sure overflow</span></div>

<div class="box" style="--d:80px"><span>Text will for sure overflow</span></div>
```

Comment: I didn't know `backdrop-filter` - thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it doesn't work in firefox and some mobile browsers.

Comment: In the second example the padding makes also the last letter in the box (partially) red...

Comment: @biberman you can rectify by adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @biberman updated my code with a smal calculation

Answer (score 2):

You can use two div to overlap on one another and hide the div behind with a background color.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.firstDiv {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.secondDiv {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='firstDiv'>Hello</div>
  <div class='secondDiv'>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `-webkit-background-clip: text` and `linear-gradient`. For that you have to wrap the text in a container with the background properties and make the target text transparent. Define the linear gradient as follows for being black for the same width like the text has (here `100px`) and the rest being red:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 100px, black 1%, red 1%);
```

**Working example:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 100px, black 1%, red 1%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

p {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible; 
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text will for sure overflow</p>
</div>
```